# showing power bi report in html using <iframe> returns "name refused to connect"

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

i have a power bi report that i need to view it in my web page, i am using power bi desktop rs (using no AccessToken idk if its the problem or not) and power bi report server configuration manager 15. [server configuration manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CvgR.png)
i can view the report on power bi web portal just fine [my report on web portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5jQA.png)

but when i create a html file and use the iframe tag to show the report on it, it says refused to connect.
[report on my html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0AFM.png)

this is my html code:

```
<iframe
    width="800"
    height="600"
    src="http://garshasp:2970/Reports/powerbi/voicebot"
    frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
```

the report is supposed to be shown in my html file

im new to all this
someone please help me, i really need this to work

Comment: Is this question in any way related to PowerShell?  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to publish the reports from Power BI Report server/ Power BI Desktop to [Power BI Service](https://app.powerbi.com/).

Refer [Publish .rdl files to Power BI from Power BI Report Server and Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/guidance/publish-reporting-services-power-bi-service?tabs=reporting-services) for publishing the report to PBI service.

Refert to [Publish Power BI Reports from PBI Desktop to PBI Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-upload-desktop-files)

Once the report gets published in Power BI Service, we can get the iframe link to embed the report.

Refer [Embed a report in a website](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure#how-to-embed-power-bi-reports-into-portals) and follow the steps to Embed your report in the website.

Comment: Feel free to reach out for any questions.

Comment: so i have to use power bi service for it ? cus i wanted it to be done on localhost, also i have the iframe link it just doesnt give me accses

Comment: Yes, We need to publish the report to PBI Service, get the iframe link and then you can do it in local host.

Comment: tanks for the assist 